# Application fails to start (0xC0000142) when load-linking to DLL that uses empty DllMain

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2017

I have a simple Visual Studio 2017 solution set up with two projects. The first project is an executable that links (load-time linking) to a DLL generated from the second project. The second project is a simple test DLL that exports a single function, and contains an empty DllMain entry point.

If I try to debug the solution, I get an error that says "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application." I tried searching for the meaning of 0xc0000142, but couldn't find anything useful from a development point of view.

If I remove the DllMain entry point from the DLL and rebuild, everything works fine.

Here is the DLL header (MyMath.h):

```
#pragma once

#ifdef THE_DLL_EXPORT
  #define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
#endif

API int AddNumbers(int a, int b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
  }
#endif
```

Here is the DLL code file (MyMath.cpp):

```
#include "MyMath.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
}

int AddNumbers(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

And here is the main code file from the first project that uses the DLL (Source.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyMath.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 4;
    cout << x << " + " << y << " = " << AddNumbers(x, y) << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Why is it empty though? It needs to return something.

Comment: Undefined behavior.  Your `DllMain` function is supposed to return a value.   Either that or don't write a `DllMain` function and let the default Windows version of that function be invoked.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I put in a return value, but the problem is still happening.

Comment: @tkausl I'd originally had some code in there with a return value of 0, since BOOL is just an int and I made the incorrect assumption that 0 meant success. I deleted the function contents to try and troubleshoot, but forgot to add back a return value (and yet it still compiled, strangely). Turns out there is a macro definition for TRUE that I wasn't aware of, which resolves to 1.

Comment: @user2498421 -- [The documentation specifies what the return values denote](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Don't guess or assume what a Windows API function is supposed to return, always read the documentation.

Comment: @PaulMckenzie No need to preach, I always do read documentation. I was tired from reading a bunch of other articles on DLLs, and was thinking it was some kind of linker error. It's been a while since I programmed DLLs in C, and there's quite a bit of minutiae to keep straight. Also, the similarity between main() and DllMain() short circuited my brain, since main() returns 0 on success, and DllMain() is conceptually identical. One of those simple but frustrating oversights that happen every once in a while. Anyway, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

DllMain wasn't returning `TRUE`. Returning `FALSE` or 0 causes the application to fail with error code 0xc0000142.

Comment: I have the same issue, the very large project failed to start due to "0xc0000142" Error. I put a break point to every DllMain and found that one of the function from one of DllMain failed. That's why the whole project failed to launch.